# Determining the rate at which a function is called with OllyDbg

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

How can I find out how many times per second a particular function is called using OllyDbg?  Alternatively, how can I count the total number of times the EIP has a certain value?

I don't want OllyDbg to break on executing this code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can accomplish this by using the trace feature, with the conditional logging, the new OllyDBG seems to implement tracing with some better features. Its been a while since I've done this, but you can check it out. But I would actually suggest using Immunity Debugger(an OllyDBG clone with python plugin interface) and maybe write a python script to do this.

Comment: I'm very familiar with Python, so I will try your suggestion. Thanks!